# Is there a way to re-render data after submit-axios post request? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I've recently started on learning React, where I've created a little project for me. Now on backend everythings works etc.

By now everything was going good, but now I've got stuck.

Now about the page: I've got page, where u can see details about single article, and get info about loan for price of article. I've made it on backend that default value of it is 60 months, and if u want different period, u submit other months value eg. 120. So on backend when I hit route http://localhost:8080/api/article/id i get response of data and loan is calculated with 60 months. Now if in body i send eg. {"months": 6} i get different data in response which is expected and working fine.

Now where I've hit a wall: on front end I have no idea how to update data when form is submited. Here you can see my from:

[image: form]

And idea is when u enter eg. 6 to lower part of page is changed:

[image: data]

These last two right clomuns should be changed.

Now I've tried to send with id months to the actions and then refresh page when disptach is triggered but no success - and I know that after refresh months are reseted to default value.

Now these values come from that localhost route and I'm fetching it with a axios call, and displaying content

Here is my Article.js component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from 'react-validation/build/form';
import Input from 'react-validation/build/input';
import CheckButton from 'react-validation/build/button';

import ArticleService from '../services/article.service';
import { getArticle } from '../actions/articles';

const Article = (props) => {
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState([]);

  const [months, setMonths] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onChangeMonths = (e) => {
    const months = e.target.value;
    setMonths(months);
  };

  const handleMonths = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setLoading(true);

    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      dispatch(getArticle(id, months))
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const res = await ArticleService.article(id);
      setContent(res.data);
      const data = res.data.kredit;
      const dataArr = [];
      dataArr.push({
        name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
        price: data.kreditNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        rate: data.rataNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        nks: data.stopaNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        banka: {
          eks: data.stopaEKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          bankname: data.ime.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          type: data.tip.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
        },
      });
      setDataArr(dataArr);
    };
    fetchPosts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const a = dataArr;

  return (
    <div>
      <p className='text-dark'>
        <Link to='/dashboard'>
          <i className='fas fa-arrow-left'></i> Nazad
        </Link>
      </p>
      <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
        <strong>Artikal id:{content.id}</strong>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Opis:
            <br></br>
            {content.descr}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena
            <br></br>
            {content.price}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena po metru kvadratnom:
            <br></br>
            {content.ppm2}/m2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        <h3>KREDITI ZA CIJENU {content.price}</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={handleMonths} ref={form}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Vrijeme otplate u mjesecima:</label>
            <Input
              type='text'
              className='form-control w-25'
              name='months'
              value={months}
              onChange={onChangeMonths}
            />

            <button
              className='btn btn-primary btn-block w-25'
              disabled={loading}
            >
              {loading && (
                <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm'></span>
              )}
              <span>Click</span>
            </button>
            <CheckButton style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={checkBtn} />

            <small>
              Ako se ne unese vrijeme otplate kredita, kredit se izračunava za
              60 mjeseci
            </small>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>

      <div className='container-fluid'>
        <br></br>
        <h4>Lista kredita</h4>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            <h4>Informacije o banci</h4>
            {a &&
              a.map((item) =>
                item.banka.bankname.map((its, index) => (
                  <div className='card card-body flex-fill'>
                    <h2>{its}</h2>
                    <h6>EKS: {item.banka.eks[index]}%</h6>
                    <h6>Tip: {item.banka.type[index]} K.S</h6>
                  </div>
                ))
              )}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            <h4>NKS</h4>
            {a &&
              a.map((item) =>
                item.nks.map((s) => (
                  <div className='card card-body flex-fill'>
                    <h2>{s}</h2>
                  </div>
                ))
              )}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            <h4>Ukupna cijena kredita</h4>
            {a &&
              a.map((item) =>
                item.price.map((it2) => (
                  <div className='card card-body flex-fill'>
                    <h2>{it2} KM</h2>
                  </div>
                ))
              )}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            <h4>Rata</h4>
            {a &&
              a.map((item) =>
                item.rate.map((it2) => (
                  <div className='card card-body flex-fill'>
                    <h2>{it2} KM/mj</h2>
                  </div>
                ))
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

actions/article.js

```
import { SET_MESSAGE, RATE_UPDATE, UPDATE_FAIL } from './types';

import ArticleService from '../services/article.service';

export const getArticle = (id, months) => (dispatch) => {
  return ArticleService.article(id, months).then(
    (response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: RATE_UPDATE,
      });

      dispatch({
        type: SET_MESSAGE,
        payload: response.data.message,
      });

      return Promise.resolve();
    },
    (error) => {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_FAIL,
      });

      dispatch({
        type: SET_MESSAGE,
        payload: message,
      });

      return Promise.reject();
    }
  );
};
```

services/article.service.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

//const API_URL = 'https://stanbackapp.azurewebsites.net/api/articles/';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/articles/';
//const dAPI_URL = 'https://stanbackapp.azurewebsites.net/api/article/';
const dAPI_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/article/';

const articles = () => {
  return axios.get(API_URL);
};

const article = (id, months) => {
  return axios.post(dAPI_URL + `${id}`, {
    months,
  });
};

export default {
  articles,
  article,
};
```

I want to frontend behave just like backend: If i don't send anything in the form display data for 60 months.(that is what is doing now), but if i type in 10 and hit click a want to page re-render these two last columns(because if you send months only them are changed) and display that new data.

Also I've tried this in dispatch:

```
dispatch(getArticle(id, months))
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
```

But `console.log` is `undefiend`

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be that you are mixing state. The first time you fetch data (via `useEffect`), you are fetching directly via axios. However, when you fetch data in the `handleMonths`, you are passing the action over to Redux, which operates very differently. The other issue is that the component never retrieves the data from Redux, so any updates are essentially ignored.

My suggestion would be to use the same method for retrieving data the first time as you do subsequent times:

```js
    const handleMonths = (e) => {
      ...

      if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
        const id = props.match.params.id;
        try {
          const res = await ArticleService.article(id, months);
          ... // Handle the response appropriately.
          setContent(res.data);
          const data = res.data.kredit;
          const dataArr = [];
          dataArr.push({
            name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
            price: data.kreditNKS,
            rate: data.rataNKS,
            nks: data.stopaNKS,
            banka: {
              eks: data.stopaEKS,
              bankname: data.ime,
              type: data.tip,
            },
          });
          setDataArr(dataArr);
        } catch (e) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
```

This provides 2 benefits:

1. You can extract the method for handling the response data to make it the same for both cases.
2. You remove the need for an external state handler (i.e. Redux) which you may not need.

Comment: I mean, I only used redux for managing user login, because it's easier to see is he authed or not. So I don't really need it. This is only single page, I will not transfer data outside this component, so I don't need redux.

Comment: I agree, you probably don't need redux in this case. If this answer solved you problem, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I've managed to get data. I've added `async` before `e`. Now I added `setContent(res.data)` hoping that after click my data will change on page but it doesn't. Any thoughts on this? EDIT: when I click, nothing happens, click starts loading and no response on the page(affect on data).

Comment: I think you need to update both `content` and `dataArr`. Your render of the columns is based on the `dataArr`, not just the content.

Comment: yep, when i added `dataArr` it changed, and at bottom added `setLoading(false)` to cancel button loading. Thanks mate! Cheers